# How to display a number without % sign in Java's JProgressBar?

Tags: jprogressbar

When I use JProgressBar, I want it to display a number from 0 to 32, not a percent, so before it starts, it will show 0, after I click start button, it will show 1 , 2 , 3 ... 32

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by overriding the [`getString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#getString%28%29http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#getString%28%29) method of [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html):

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends javax.swing.JProgressBar {

    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return getValue() + "";
    }

}
```

Assuming you set the min and max values to 0 and 32 respectively, and the progress values using the `setValue()` method, your progress bar will now show integers from 0 to 32.

And here is a working example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class ProgressBarExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final CustomProgressBar customProgressBar = new CustomProgressBar();
        customProgressBar.setMaximum(32);
        customProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                int value = 0;
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                while (value < customProgressBar.getMaximum()) {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                    value ++;
                    customProgressBar.setValue(value);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, customProgressBar, "Progress bar example", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```